# ExtJS - Applying JQUery UI themes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, extjs, extjs4

I am in the process of replacing a few JQueryUI components with ExtJS. The issue I am currently facing is how to apply our JQuery theme in ExtJS.

For example, my popup windows use `.ui-icon-close-thick`. However, to override this in ExtJS I need to set the `.x-tool-close` class to the `same background-image` & `background-position`. Does anyone know an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do that — like there is no easy way to take the exterior off a car and seamlessly attach it onto the frame body of another car made by other vendor. Ext JS components are represented by certain distinctive DOM structures which your CSS rules should fit to.

The right way to do that (not very easy though) would be to [create your own Ext JS theme](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/guide/theming) that will mimic your jQuery theme.

Comment: after searching into the dark corners of the web, I am saddened to accept your answer. =P